# the fundamental group of $X$ is the symmetric group $S_3$, then whether it has a universal cover?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups, path-connected

**Question:** Suppose that $X$ is a path-connected space with $\pi_1(X)=S_3$, which is the 3-symmetric group. I just wonder that whether $X$ has a universal cover.

**Try:** Based on Hatcher, $X$ has a universal cover iff $X$ is path-connected, locally path-connected, and semilocally simply-connected. However, to prove that $X$ meets the latter two conditions is not easy.

I know that $X$ with $\pi_1(X)=S_3$ can be realized by a CW complex and any CW complex meets these three conditions so that has a universal cover. But this is not the way to show that any such $X$ has a universal cover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowledge of $\pi_1(X)$ and nothing else will not tell you that $X$ is path-connected, locally so, or semilocally simply-connected.  Since Hatcher's criteria is an "if and only if" your question has no definite answer as written.  The closest you may be able to get is via a CW-approximation which would be correct up to (weak) homotopy, but would not say anything about $X$ itself.

Comment: we have supposed that $X$ is path connected.

Comment: Right, but then you need to get locally p-c and semilocally s-c, and all of these properties are independent.